# Possible Converse to a Corollary to the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $\mathsf{K}$ be a field, and $A$ a finite dimensional associative $\mathsf{K}$-algebra, and suppose that $\mathcal{L}$ is a complete collection of representatives of the isomorphism classes of irreducible left $A$-modules. If $A$ is semisimple, then a corollary to the Artin-Wedderburn theorem states that

$$
\dim_{\mathsf{K}} A = \sum_{L \in \mathcal{L}} (\dim_{\mathsf{K}}L)^{2}.
$$

I am interested in whether this corollary has a converse. That is, if this equality holds can we say that $A$ is semisimple? If the answer is yes is there a simple (semisimple?) argument that I'm missing here, or if it is false can you provide a counter-example? If it is false, are there extra suppositions that we can apply to $A$ or $\mathsf{K}$ to make the statement hold? (Perhaps characteristic zero or algebraically closed?)

Comment: I'm confused about the corollary of Artin-Wedderburn that you mention at the beginning: presumably you should assume $K$ is algebraically closed (or that $A$ is *split* semisimple)? For instance if $K=\mathbf{R}$ and $A=\mathbf{C}$ then the left-hand side is $2$ but the right hand side is $4$ (there being one irreducible $A$-module, namely $A$, of dimension $2$ over $K=\mathbf{R}$).

Comment: Ah yes, I think the extra condition that I actually want is that the modules L are absolutely irreducible (which of course is satisfied if $\mathsf{K}$ is algebraically closed), but I need the result in a case where $\mathsf{K}$ is not algebraically closed, for instance $\mathsf{K} = \mathbb{Q}(t)$. Of course this is needed because the proof of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem uses that $\operatorname{End}_{A}(S) \cong \mathsf{K}$ for any irreducible $A$-module $S$, which is only true is $\mathsf{K}$ is algebraically closed (or $S$ is absolutely irreducible)

Comment: Well, the most general (and also the most widely cited) version of Artin-Wedderburn does not in fact assume that the algebra is split (that it, that every irreducible is absolutely irreducible), and the conclusion is that a semi-simple algebra is a direct sum of matrix rings over division algebras over $K$. In any case, the result you are wondering about is false without some additional hypothesis (see below). I guess it is true if $A$ is split, though.

Comment: Sure. I understand that that is the statement of Artin-Wedderburn. I am not looking for a strict converse to Artin-Wedderburn, but rather to the corollary to Artin-Wedderburn that if $\mathsf{K}$ is algebraically closed (or I suppose that all irreducible $A$-modules are absolutely irreducible), then this dimension formula holds. I suppose what I'm looking for is a result like "Suppose that $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$ whose irreducible modules are absolutely irreducible, and such that this dimension formula holds, then $A$ is semisimple.

Comment: Well, that is true (the proof is immediate; see my answer below).

Comment: Thank you! That was precisely the sort of argument I was looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: consider $A=\mathbf{C}[t]/(t^2)$ and $K=\mathbf{R}$. $A$ has one irrep, namely $\mathbf{C}$, of dimension $2$ over $\mathbf{R}$, and the dimension of $A$ over $\mathbf{R}$ is $4=2^2$, but $A$ is not semi-simple.

The issue is that there are two competing forces at work here: $A$ is not semi-simple, which tends to *decrease* the number of irreducibles relative to the semi-simple case, but also not split, which tends to *increase* the dimensions of the irreducibles.

If you assume that every irreducible representation is absolutely irreducible, then the result it true: the right-hand side is in this case the dimension of the semi-simplification $A/\mathrm{Jrad}(A)$ of $A$ (here $\mathrm{Jrad}(A)$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$); if this is equal to the dimension of $A$ then $\mathrm{Jrad}(A)=0$ as desired.

Comment: If I could upvote this answer twice then I would!

Comment: @AdamHiggins Thanks, glad I could help!